# Как поставить flex-детей в начало, при уменьшении экрана?

Tags: css, flexbox

Делаю навигационный бар.

На больших экранах все выглядит так, как мне нужно.

Проблема с маленькими экранами.

При уменьшении экрана, flex-дети должны прижаться к левому краю.
Но этого не происходит. Они центрируются.

Вот как это выглядит у меня на экране:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно, чтобы это выглядело вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Медиазапросы и прочее использовать нельзя. Условие задачи: только флексы и ничего больше.

Так как же мне получить такой же эффект, что и на картинке?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 8px;
}

.footer-name {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.footer-nav-item {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer-nav-item {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-button {
    font-size: 8px;
    background: inherit;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 4px 4px;
}

.white {
    color: white;
}

.footer-margin {
    margin: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
    <title>Flex navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="footer-name footer-margin white">Rio Coffee</p>

        <nav class="footer-nav footer-margin">
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">HOME</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">MENU</a>
        </nav>
        
        <button class="footer-button footer-margin white">CONTACT</button>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, задание на флексы, препод не разрешает юзать медиа-запросы. Он говорит, что можно без них

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще на самом деле оно слева встанет, если задать `space-between`. Но всё равно это не способ задать поведение на меньшей версии, а просто так работает. И лучше, конечно, задавать через media-запросы с явным указанием позиции (`flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;`), чтобы избежать лишних проблем (например, сейчас при определенной ширине на одном уровне повиснет меню и подобие логотипа, но кнопка контактов перекатится на следующий уровень).

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 8px;
}

.footer > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer-name {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.footer-nav-item {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.footer-nav-item {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-button {
    font-size: 8px;
    background: inherit;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 4px 4px;
}

.white {
    color: white;
}

.footer-margin {
    margin: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
    <title>Flex navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="footer-name footer-margin white">Rio Coffee</p>

        <nav class="footer-nav footer-margin">
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">HOME</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">MENU</a>
        </nav>
        
        <button class="footer-button footer-margin white">CONTACT</button>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

так что Ваш преподаватель скорее некореектно поставил задачу.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.footer-name {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-nav-item {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer-nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-button {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: inherit;
  padding: 4px 4px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.footer-margin {
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-name {
    display: flex;
    width: 290px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
     padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .footer-button {
    display: flex;
    width: 290px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
     padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/reset.css">
  <title>Flex navigation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="footer-name footer-margin white ">Rio Coffee</p>

    <nav class="footer-nav footer-margin">
      <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">HOME</a>
      <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">SERVICES</a>
      <a class="footer-nav-item white" href="#">MENU</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="footer-button footer-margin white">
      <button>CONTACT</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).